# MPAndroid candlestick combined with volume bar chart height issue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, candlestick-chart

I need suggestion on how to limit the MpAndroid CandleStick chart combined with volume bar chart at the bottom so that volume bar max height can be limit  to below 1/3 of chart area Yaxis . From the chart attached , this is somewhere Y Max at 3million region viewport  in the left Axis. The current combined chart is ruin by the volume bar chart.   [image: current combined chart here]

Thanks

Comment: how do you put dates on axis X ?

Answer (score 0):

- setVisibleXRangeMaximum(float maxXRange): Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be maximum visible at once. If this is e.g. set to 10, no more than 10 values on the x-axis can be viewed at once without scrolling.
- setVisibleXRangeMinimum(float minXRange): Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be minimum visible at once. If this is e.g. set to 10, it is not possible to zoom in further than 10 values on the x-axis.
- setVisibleYRangeMaximum(float maxYRange, AxisDependency axis): Sets the size of the area (range on the y-axis) that should be maximum visible at once. You also need to provide the axis this constraint should apply to.

For more info [Refer this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment ,I do not think setting XrangeMax or Min will help , it only limit the  x-axis down to certain visible display range instead of showing the full range of the dataset points . The chart shown above has about more than 4000 data points , I have  narrowed the visible x-range using set chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100) and also  chart.moveViewToX(3000) to optimise performance. What I need is some functional procedure   to set the max Y-axis (eg left Y-axis) at certain specific offset position , so that the lower portion of the chart could be restricted  to the volume bar chart by clipping the specific rectangle viewports. I am not sure if that is possible , narrowing the YVsibleYrange is not what I have in mind.  What I would like to have is [image]

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Brother , at that time ,comment could not fit all those reply , why are you so concern with this , put more emphasis on solution rather than focus on this sort of trivial matter and hate to see  nonsense solution offer  !!

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. All you need to do is plot the data against two different axes (as you are already doing), and then set the top space for each axis separately.

**Customizing the axis range**

- `setAxisMaxValue(float max)`: Set a custom maximum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.
- `setAxisMinValue(float min)`: Set a custom minimum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.
- `setSpaceTop(float percent)`: Sets the top spacing (in percent of the total axis-range) of the highest value in the chart in comparison to the highest value on the axis.
- `setSpaceBottom(float percent)`: Sets the bottom spacing (in percent of the total axis-range) of the lowest value in the chart in comparison to the lowest value on the axis.

More information in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-%28YLabels%29).

Comment: it works by using setSpaceTop and setSpaceBottom. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To workaround   , I have coded the Y axis to be at  1/x1  of Y viewport height  to mark the volume bar top at YMAX in the multiple of x1  where x1 variable can be ={3, 4 or 5}       float ymax=barDataSet.getYMax();  float ymaxd=(float)Math.floor (ymax*x1);                            leftAxis.setLabelCount(x1,false);                         leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(ymaxd);